# want to remove my password or change in win10

Tags: passwords

during re-install of win10 my computer split user accounts into 2 but i got locked out of  the administrative account during the re-install. Now I cant add or update certain programs. Im  in the duplicate account but I don't have administrative rights

Comment: Use any live cd/dvd/flash with any software which allows offline edition of userlist and/or user's password(s). Change/remove password of existing user or create new one having admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the Windows 10 Administrator password is actually a joke, Microsoft has no such thing as real security. Officially Microsoft suggests that you follow the article linked below and the steps that follow:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/account-reset-password-forgot-faq

Further if you are unable to get access that on your system, I suggest you to go to Windows Recovery Environment and use the Command Prompt there, which is elevated.

Follow the below steps:-

1)      Press Shift and Restart from the power icon (together)

2)      Select Troubleshoot.

3)      Go to Advanced Options.

4)      Select Command Prompt.

5)      Type "net user Administrator /active:yes"

6)      Hit Enter.

A user account with the name Admin will be created. Log in with that account and you will be able to access Admin privileges. You can also create more Administrator accounts with that account.

If those steps are a little too confusing, [here's an excellent article](http://web.archive.org/web/20180824233927/https://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/) with lots of photos, detailed steps and it's offered by a great source (How To Geek).

Now back to breaking Windows and its non-existent security, you can always use an offline software tool that cracks (discovers) or resets all the user account passwords on your computer. A couple tools capable of offline password cracking and resetting (respectively) are OPHCrack ([How to Geek article here!](http://web.archive.org/web/20180824224135/https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29694/how-to-crack-your-forgotten-windows-password/)) or if you simply want to reset a password without learning the current one, you could try something like [Trinity](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=0._QUICK_AND_DIRTY_GUIDE_TO_USING_TRK&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) which allows you to boot from a USB or CD/DVD like OPHCrack but rather than decrypting the password, it resets it to null or whatever you want it to be.

Good luck, have fun and don't use any of this information on a computer that doesn't belong to you, or more specifically you don't have permission to change/modify.